# C++: Error when attempting to print starting from second node in the linked list (dummy node)

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm writing a program that is supposed to allow the user to enter a course to a linked list (addCourse) and return all the data put in the linked list (displayAll). I'm trying to put all new course data in front of the linked list which means old data will be pushed backed every time a new course is added.

I'm fairly new to C++ (came from Java) so my apologies if this all seems elementary.

What I'm trying to do is:

- Create a new node in main **(Done)**.
- Make that the head of the list for now **(Done)**.
- Create a new node **(Done)**.
- Create a pointer named **temp** and make that point to a new node **(Done)**.
- Make **temp** point to the head of the list **(Done)**.
- Whatever data the user enters gets put into the node temp is pointing at (in this case, the head) **(Done)**
- When that's done, temp should create and point to a new empty node (for the next time the user inputs something) and make what used to be head the next node in the list. ***(Not sure if I got this part right in my code)***.

I believe this is called a dummy node.

Here's my code so far:

**Header:**

```
struct node
{
    string department;
    int number;
    string grade;
    node* next;
};
```

**Main**:

```
int main()
{
    string department;
    int number;
    string grade;

    node* head;
    int n;


    cout << "1 - Insert a Course" << endl;
    cout << "2 - Remove a Course" << endl;
    cout << "3 - Display Course List (All)" << endl;
    cout << "4 - Display Course List (Department)" << endl;
    cout << "5 - Quit this Program" << endl;


    start(head, n, department, number, grade);

    return 0;
}
```

**"Start" Function:**

```
// start of the program
void start(node* &head, int n, string department, int number, string grade)
{

    cout << "Please enter a number: ";
    cin >> n;

    if (n == 1)
    {
        addCourse(department, number, grade);
    }
    else if (n == 2)
    {
        removeCourse(head, department, number);
    }

    else if (n == 3)
    {
        displayAll(head);
    }

    else if (n == 4)
    {
        displayDep(head, department);
    }

    else if (n == 5)
    {
        quitProgram();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Invalid input. Please try again." << endl;
        cin.get();
        start(head, n, department, number, grade);
    }
    start(head, n, department, number, grade);
}
```

**addCourse (Function):**

```
void addCourse(node* head, string department, int number, string grade)
{
    // make temp point to the head of the list
    node* temp = head;

    cout << "Department: ";
    cin >> department;
    cout << "Number: ";
    cin >> number;
    cout << "Grade: ";
    cin >> grade;

    // put data in the head of the list    
    temp->department = department;
    temp->number = number;
    temp->grade = grade;

    // create a new node for later
    temp = new node;
    temp->next = head;
    head = temp;
}
```

**Function of Concern (displayAll)**

```
// displays all data
void displayAll(node* head)
{
    // **Area of concern
    node* temp = head;
    temp = head->next;

    // I'm trying to print data starting from the second node in the list
    // since the first is technically empty. The program compiles but I
    // get an error when I try to run that part of the code.

    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        cout << "Department: " << temp->department << endl;
        cout << "Number: " << temp->number << endl;
        cout << "Grade: " << temp->grade << endl;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to start printing from the second node in the list since the first is empty (a dummy node) but the program keeps failing whenever I try to do that. Am I writing that part of my code properly? I will include the error in a moment.

*UPDATE: Yeah. No error. It just crashes in Visual Studio when you try to run **displayAll**. I was using XCode earlier.*

And my apologies again if this seems elementary to you guys. I'm fairly new to this. This is part of a program I've been assembling all week (as you've probably already noticed from the start function). Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

When the `main` function starts, the value of the variable `head` is *indeterminate*, using it in any way without initialization leads to *undefined behavior*. As far as I can see, you never initialize it. You should initialize to a null-pointer, e.g. `nullptr` or `0`.

You *also* have a problem with passing arguments *by value*, which means that the argument you pass to a function are *copied*, and changing a copy (e.g. reassigning `head` in the `addCourse` function) will not change the original. You need to pass some variables *by reference*.